# what is a unitary operator

Tags: linear-algebra

I am alittle confused about the unitary operator since I have seen many definitions

- a linear operator in an inner product space is unitary if $$\Vert T(x)\Vert =\Vert x\Vert $$
- a linear transformation on an I.P.S is said to be unitary operator if

i- T is 1-1

ii- T preserves inner product

- T is linear operator if it is  invertible and preserves inner product

s0 do a 1-1 transformation need be invertible 
and if so what is the difference between isomorphism and unitary since I know that  T is isomorphism if it is invertible and preserves  inner product

Comment: In an infinite-dimensional space, a map satisfying $\|Tx\|=\|x\|$ may be injective but not surjective.

Comment: There exist non-invertible one-to-one maps. Unitary maps are invertible isometries - i.e., distance preserving.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_operator wherein all is explained clearly.

Answer (score 2):

For finite dimensional inner product spaces, every 1-1 operator is also an isomorphism. However, unitary operators are special isomorphisms which preserve lengths and inner products. For example, the operator which scales every vector by 2 is an isomorphism, but is not unitary.

In infinite dimensional vector spaces, not every 1-1 operator is invertible. For example, in the space $\ell^2$ of square summable sequences, the right shift operator is 1-1 but not onto; every sequence in its range begins with a zero. This operator preserves inner products, but it is not unitary because it is not invertible.